# How can I remove spaces in XML feeds?

Tags: 7, feeds, xml-sitemap

I am working on creating the XML feeds for the contents of a specific content type. But after creating XML feeds, I noticed that the blank space is appearing at top of the XML feeds.

How can I remove that?

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Does that invalidate the feed? Is this maybe just browser style? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Maybe try Feeds Tamper and trim white space?

Comment: @leymannx yes.... its showing invalidate. As per work-around, I tried to find space before <?php tag .. but there is no space before php tag..